# Parsing content from one table and then insert the result of parsing to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables :

```
Table document
============================================================================
| id_document | document_address |              document_content           |
============================================================================
|      1      |        C         |Example sentences A. Example sentences B.|
|      2      |        D         |Example sentences C. Example sentences D.|
============================================================================
```

I want to separate document_content based on dot and insert them into sentence table with their doc_id so the sentence table will contain :

```
Table sentence :
 ======================================================================
 |  id_row  |  id_document |   id_sentence   |       sentence         | 
 ======================================================================
 |     1    |       1      |       0         | Example sentences A    |
 |     2    |       1      |       1         | Example sentences B    |
 |     3    |       2      |       0         | Example sentences C    |
 |     4    |       2      |       1         | Example sentences D    |
 ======================================================================
```

Here's the code :

```
<?php

require_once 'conf.php';

$doc_id = array();
// get the doc_id
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_document FROM document");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $doc_id[] = $row['id_document'];
}

//get the content
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT document_content FROM document WHERE id_document IN (' . implode(",", $doc_id) . ')') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $sentence[] = $row['document_content'];
}

$i = 0;
foreach ($sentence as $sentences){
  // Separate based on dot
  $saveSentence = preg_split('/\\.\\s*/', $sentences);
   $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sentence VALUES('','$doc_id','$i','$saveSentence','') ");
$i++;
}

?>
```

but the doc_id cannot be read and the array of content cannot be inserted to table. Help me please. thank you very much : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't fetch doc_id
replace

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT document_content FROM document WHERE id_document IN (' . implode(",", $doc_id) . ')') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $sentence[] = $row['document_content'];
}

$i = 0;
foreach ($sentence as $sentences){
// Separate based on dot
  $saveSentence = preg_split('/\\.\\s*/', $sentences);
   $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sentence VALUES('','$doc_id','$i','$saveSentence','') ");
$i++;
}
```

with

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT id_document, document_content FROM document WHERE id_document IN (' . implode(",", $doc_id) . ')') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $sentence[$row['id_document']] = $row['document_content'];
}

foreach ($sentence as $doc_id => $sentences)
{
  $i = 0;
  foreach(preg_split('/\\.\\s*/', $sentences) as $current_sentence)
  {
    $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sentence SET id_document = {$doc_id}, id_sentence = {$i}, sentence = '{$current_sentence}'");
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, thank you so much @Puggan Se ! how about the content that I have to separate them first, so I can get every sentence and then insert them to the different rows in sentence table..

Comment: i added the 2nd loop to my answer, and rewrited your insert to a `INSERT .. SET` for readability